# My number of rep-capped days is strange

Tags: support, reputation

In my `/reputation`:

```
days represented 627
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 15 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 13 days
earned 242 reputation from suggested edits
```

Surely the value on the 3rd line should be greater than or equal to the value on the 2nd?

I've done some investigation:

[Here is my `/reputation`, in full](http://pastebin.com/XkapcBcb)
[Here is only those days on which I have capped || reached 200 rep](http://pastebin.com/5sMS1XC1)

My calculations:

```
-- 2011-05-04 (200+, cap)   
-- 2011-05-13 (200+, cap)    
-- 2011-05-15 (200+, cap) 
-- 2011-05-26 (cap)
-- 2011-05-27 (200+, cap)  
-- 2011-05-31 (200+, cap) 
-- 2011-08-10 (200+, cap)  
-- 2011-08-17 (200+, cap)  
-- 2011-10-15 (200+, cap) 
-- 2012-01-11 (200+)
-- 2012-01-31 (200+, cap)   
-- 2012-02-01 (200+, cap) 
-- 2012-09-26 (200+, cap)
-- 2013-03-18 (200+, cap)
```

Leading to days of 200+ to be 13 and capped days to be 13. Somehow I've gained two days of cap! I searched through `/reputation` for `(-` to find all downvotes that might have added days with <200 rep where I still capped, but I can only find the one.

Comment: I think, as stated, the first rep cap calculation (for some reason) only checks count of upvotes, not actual rep earned

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe it's because it's possible to reach the rep cap but without reaching 200 rep?

e.g. reaching the rep cap and getting downvoted, or reaching the rep cap and giving away a bounty.

Comment: I've done some investigation, I have done this once, but as far as I can tell, only once.